# How to view row data as column without loosing duplicate raw values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a dashboard where I have the data in this format .

[image]

I would like to view the data so that the roles becomes a column and show officials under each roles like this . I tried to use Pivot in my store precedure before bringing this data into power bi but my only problem using Pivot is that I had to use Max(Officialname) and due to which official who has duplicate roles under same branch were excluded and showed me the first row. For example In the branch "Bedford" there are two "Secretary" roles under officialname "John" and "Mike", using pivot I was getting only "Mike", I was wondering if there are any option to represent the data as shown in the second table t2 please. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have used the below query and I'm getting the required result, however I'm loosing officials who has same role under same branch, how can I over come this problem.

```
SELECT  Branch, President, Treasurer,Secretary,Role_Status
FROM    #pivot  PIVOT ( max(official_name) FOR committee_type IN ([President],[Treasurer],[Secretary]) ) AS PivotTable
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use images - use formatted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple case statement,

```
select Branch, case when Role = 'Treasure' then OfficialName end as Treasure,
case when Role = 'Secretary' then OfficialName end as Secretary,
case when Role = 'President' then OfficialName end as President
  from table;
```

Comment: Case is an **expression** not a statement!